# external harddisk bitlocker, how it's possible to have dictionary attack, or some another code

Tags: bitlocker

5 years ago, I locked my external hard disk with Bitlocker in Windows 7.

I forgot the password and I don't have the recovery key as well. How can I access my data?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/search?tab=votes&q=bitlocker%20forgotten

Comment: I suggest looking into bitlocker vulnerabilities published since the times you encrypted the drive. BitLeaker tool is an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

That's the whole point of hard disk encryption -- to protect the contents from users who don't have the password or the recovery key. If it was easy to break into, it'd be... well... broken.